# docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim flags: 0xe: permission denied: unknown

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, docker-compose, containers

I installed docker on my ubuntu- 20.04 server by [this link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) from official website and i wanted to run nginx container. docker is installed successfully but  When I try to create and run a container for example (sudo docker run hello-world) or (sudo run -p 80:80 -d nginx) or ..., this error shows up:

---

`docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "proc" to rootfs at "/proc": mount proc:/proc (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0xe: permission denied: unknown.  ERRO[0002] error waiting for container:`

---

it is worth mentioning that the container is created but is not able to be run.

[image]

[image]

I tried lot's of solution on the internet but those didn't work. can anybody help me out to solve this ?

Comment: please don't paste text as screenshots

Comment: Have you tried `docker run hello-world` ? without sudo.

Comment: yes. also the same error returns